# Why is $|e^{i \lambda z}| |e^{- \lambda y}|= |e^{- \lambda y}|$ here?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z \in \Gamma (R)$ where this is the upper semi circle centred at the origin with radius $R>1$. Let $z=x+iy$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \geq 0$. So

$$|e^{i \lambda z}|=|e^{i \lambda z}| |e^{- \lambda y}|= |e^{- \lambda y}|$$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

How can the last equality possibly be true?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ real or possibly complex?

Comment: Where did you get $|e^{i\lambda z}|=|e^{i\lambda z}||e^{-\lambda y}|$?

Comment: Well it is from a function. In my notes, they were trying to find an upper bound for the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^{i \lambda z}}{z^2 +1}$$ and they had that written down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you mean $|e^{i\lambda z}| = |e^{i\lambda x}||e^{-\lambda y}|$. This equality follows from the fact that $z = x + iy$:

$$e^{i\lambda z} = e^{i\lambda(x+iy)} = e^{i\lambda x - \lambda y} = e^{i\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}.$$

Then, as $\lambda, x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|e^{i\lambda x}| = 1$. To see this, note that $e^{i\lambda x} = \cos(\lambda x) + i\sin(\lambda x)$, so

$$|e^{i\lambda x}|^2 = \cos^2(\lambda x) + \sin^2(\lambda x) = 1$$

so $|e^{i\lambda x}| = 1$.

Comment: Good interpretation.

Comment: shhhhhhhhhhhhhhh did not see that!!